# How to save ACF custom field alongside when a plugin auto publishes a post

Tags: php, wordpress

To give context to what I am doing, I have a plugin which scrapes data from another website. So I created the two fields in anticipation of the data which goes into the ACF custom fields. Everything is fine except that I am having to manually refresh each post page in admin so that the ACF custom fields are saved to the postmeta table. Right now the data appears to display in the custom fields as placeholder/default. But when I refresh, data is saved in the db.
I hope to achieve:
Saving data into the database both for the new posts and existing posts.

The code:

```
<?php

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=application_email', function ($field) {
    $howtoapply = get_field('howtoapply');
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'application_email', true) == '') {

        $apply_link = get_field('howtoapply');

        $link = $apply_link;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($link);
        $dom->loadHTML($link);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
        }

        function cfDecodeEmail($encodedString)
        {
            $k = hexdec(substr($encodedString, 0, 2));
            for ($i = 2, $email = ''; $i < strlen($encodedString) - 1; $i += 2) {
                $email .= chr(hexdec(substr($encodedString, $i, 2)) ^ $k);
            }
            return $email;
        }

        if (!is_null($a) && is_object($a)) {

            $field['value'] = cfDecodeEmail($a->getAttribute('data-cfemail'));
            $GLOBALS[$field['value']] = cfDecodeEmail($a->getAttribute('data-cfemail'));

            if (!add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value'])) {
                update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value']);
            }
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    }

    return $field;
});
```

With thanks

Comment: Doesn't ACF have a hook for saving information? Seems like your missing a secondary database entry. You could turn on SQL logging and look before and after the refresh to see what's being stored.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. Why are you save the post meta on `load_field` filter ? You should be saving the post meta on `update_field` filter. By the time your page loads the post meta probably has already ran through it's loading cycle so you don't see it on the first load, that's why you see it on refresh.

Comment: Using ```add_filter('acf/update_valuename=application_email', function($field) {...} ```causes the ACF custom fields to be blank.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `add_filter('acf/update_field/name=application_email', function($field) {...}` ?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo but still did work like that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is this hook us running after the the post_meta fields have already been loaded by Wordpress. This is why you're seeing them on a page refresh.

I believe what you're after is so save the post_meta fields at the point where the ACF fields are updated. so change your hook to `acf/update_field/name`

```
<?php

add_filter('acf/update_field/name=application_email', function ($field) {
    $howtoapply = get_field('howtoapply');
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'application_email', true) == '') {

        $apply_link = get_field('howtoapply');

        $link = $apply_link;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($link);
        $dom->loadHTML($link);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
        }

        function cfDecodeEmail($encodedString)
        {
            $k = hexdec(substr($encodedString, 0, 2));
            for ($i = 2, $email = ''; $i < strlen($encodedString) - 1; $i += 2) {
                $email .= chr(hexdec(substr($encodedString, $i, 2)) ^ $k);
            }
            return $email;
        }

        if (!is_null($a) && is_object($a)) {

            $field['value'] = cfDecodeEmail($a->getAttribute('data-cfemail'));
            $GLOBALS[$field['value']] = cfDecodeEmail($a->getAttribute('data-cfemail'));

            if (!add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value'])) {
                update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'application_email', $field['value']);
            }
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    }

    return $field;
});
```

You may had to modify the function a function a little because you're depending on another field `howtoapply` which may not exist, depending on the order of operations.

Comment: The ```howtoapply``` field always has a value.  I tried the above code but the Custom fields are blank. I also checked the database there is now no meta keys for the posts imported using the new filter ```acf/update_field```

Comment: Hmm, then my new suspicions is you were never getting a good result from this code. You should log some info to see where the hangup is. The meta fields were probably being updated by the ACF plugin itself when you were on the admin posts page.

Comment: It appears the code is not being run at the time when the plugin is creating a post. Somehow I need to connect them. Not sure how.